# Error when following Python Password Vault tutorial : "cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest."

Tags: python, cryptography, fernet

I'm a beginner and I followed this YT tutorial and happened to encountered an error he didn't have.
https://youtu.be/QBSAfahLuSk?t=1264

So what happened was, after I changed the master password, my password vault is empty. it didn't carry over the previous master password's passwords vault and produced numbers of error in the output.

A lot of the outputs was error in tkinter fernet but one of it said it was something wrong with this code

```
def decrypt(message: bytes, token: bytes) -> bytes:
    return Fernet(token).decrypt(message)
```

```
if cursor.fetchall() is not None:
        i = 0
        while True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            array = cursor.fetchall()

            if (len(array) == 0):
                break

            lbl1 = Label(second_frame, text=(decrypt(array[i][1], encryptionKey)))
            lbl1.grid(column=0, row=i + 3)
            lbl2 = Label(second_frame, text=(decrypt(array[i][2], encryptionKey)))
            lbl2.grid(column=1, row=i + 3)
            lbl3 = Label(second_frame, text=(decrypt(array[i][3], encryptionKey)))
            lbl3.grid(column=2, row=i + 3)

            btn = Button(second_frame, text="Delete", command=partial(removeEntry, array[i][0]))
            btn.grid(column=6, row=i + 3, pady=10)

            i = i + 1

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            if len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i:
                break
```

here's the full error:

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 133, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 72, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line 85, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\desktop\opensesame.py", line 150, in done
    vaultScreen()
  File "c:\Users\user\desktop\opensesame.py", line 327, in vaultScreen
    lbl1 = Label(second_frame, text=(decrypt(array[i][1], encryptionKey)))
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\desktop\opensesame.py", line 33, in decrypt
    return Fernet(token).decrypt(message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 90, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, time_info)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 151, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 135, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Comment: Please put the actual full stacktrace of the error into your post. Just that error message itself is practically useless.

Comment: hi I edited it, please take a look

Comment: Thanks. I edited your title so that it contains the actual error itself.

Comment: thx. btw this is the entire code. I copy pasted the exact thing and still get the same error. it'd be nice if someone can try it on their end and see if its just me error or what

https://github.com/Gomez0015/PythonPasswordVault/blob/main/password_vault.py